# iBeacon mobile web application development

Tags: ios7, mobile-safari, mobile-website, ibeacon

Are there any custom APIs for iBeacon access from mobile web applications? Probably it could be a mobile safari extension.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

You could write a native iOS app that looks for iBeacons in the background and launches a specific web app URL on mobile Safari.  You could even pass ranged beacon info in query parameters.

But you would still need a native app installed on the phone to do this.  And once the Safari page is launched, getting further updates is impossible, unless you use a complex web service proxy to the native app.

Comment: Thanks davidgyoung for the note. I was experimenting the ways of accessing native capabilities via mobile web.