# ibeacon with HTML5 webpage

Tags: html, ibeacon

I am new guy to get know the IBeacon technology, as I understand taht IBecaon can invoke APP, I am thinking is it possible that we just use mobile phone webpage browser(HTML5), not to use the pre-installed APP. 
    In this way, can IBeacon send out the proximity signal as it always does and therefore to update the contents in the mobile phone webpage according to different IBeacon ID.
    Is it difficult to implement this webpage and the back-end web service.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible.  Unfortunately there are no standard HTML5 bindings to detect iBeacons.  Building custom bindings would require you to build your own web browser.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19968977/1461050) for more info.